# XML validation via DTD with "|"-character. Exclusive or and how to use it?

Tags: xml, dtd

I have a hard time wrapping my head around the | character used in DTDs to define which elements can be contained in another element. I tried google for quite a while, but none of the major results tackles that topic in a manner I can understand - might be just me sitting in front of a wall staring vividly.

Imagine the following example. I have an element named "response" that can either contain an unordered and undefined number of the tags "character" and "player" or exactely one tag "base" and an undefinied amount of "option" tags. As in:

```
<response>
    <character>text</character>
    <player>text</player>
    <character>text</character>
</response>
```

is valid. Also:

```
<response>
    <base>text</base>
    <option>other elements</option>
    <option>other elements</option>
    <option>other elements</option>
</response>
```

is valid as well. However, a mixture of character/player and base/option tags is not valid.
I tried the following in my DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT response ((character*, player*)
                   |(base, option*))>
```

however, this did not lead to any proper validation. Some kind of

```
<!ELEMENT response (character*, player*, 
                    base*, option*)>
```

is not exactely what I want and my editor also cries if I do character->player->character in my hierarchy.
w3schools and some other pages tell me, something like

```
<!ELEMENT response (character | player | base 
                   | option)*>
```

would be mixed content and I could just throw stuff in my tags as I would like to (or at least, that's what I'm lead to believe), but this is neither what I want, nor seems my editor to be happy with it.

So, I would be very happy if someone could tell me the proper use of the | character when defining elements in DTDs. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Edited the - of course false - #REQUIRED tags out of the declarations. Didn't use them in my code, just messed up writing this.

[Edit:  removed an erroneous reference to 'mixed content' in the question title.]

Comment: i don't think you're using the term "mixed content" correctly, see: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp

Comment: If "mixed content" applies to only content that mixes CDATA and tags propably not, but well, there you can see how little I was actually able to understand of it. ;) However, your link helps me little as it's talking about xsd and I try to validate with dtds.

Comment: @NathanHughes is right about the term "mixed content". Here's a link that might be more helpful: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close! Try this:

```
<!ELEMENT response ((character|player)*|(base,option*))>
```

Also note that the `#REQUIRED` has been removed from the declaration. You only want that in the attribute declarations (`ATTLIST`). If you would've removed it, your very last attempt would've worked as well:

```
<!ELEMENT response (character | player | base | option)*>
```

Comment: Eh, forget about that     #REQUIRED - I only wrote that here for no reason at all (as in: "I'm stupid"), not in my own code. Notepad++ with XML still gives me errors with what you wrote:    "Element response content does not follow the DTD, expecting ((character* | player*) | (base , option*)), got (character player character )"

Comment: @Aerius - Are you sure you have it exactly like I wrote? `(character*|player*)` is saying "zero or more character elements or zero or more player elements". Make sure you remove the inner `*` and move it to the outside: `(character|player)*` (This means zero or more character or player elements.)

Comment: Ah, I see! Now, that made all the difference in the world. Thank you for that explanation, that was exactely the point I didn't understand.